# Theorem : (Limit) Let $f : E →\mathbb{R}$ be a function with domain E and suppose that x is a point of 0 accumulation of E.

Tags: limits

> Theorem : (Limit) Let $f : E →\mathbb{R}$ be a function with domain E and suppose that $x_{0}$ is a point of accumulation of E. Then we write $\lim_{x \to x_0} f (x) = L $ if for every sequence $\{e_n \}$of points of E with $e_n  \neq x$ and $e_n →x_0$ as $n →+∞ $
>
> $$\lim_{n\to +\infty} f (e_n ) = L$$

now if $\lim_{x \to x_0} f (x) = -\infty$ then How is that ?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Let $E = (0,1]$ and let $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by

$$ f(x) = -1/x $$

Then $0$ is an accumulation point of $E$ and let $e_{n} = 1/n$.

Then $e_{n} \to 0$ and $f(e_{n}) \to -\infty$ and hence

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = -\infty $$

Comment: This is not a proof according to the definition: you have to show that *for every sequence…*

Comment: @egreg I understand your point. However, I think the OP is asking how can the limit be $-\infty$. Of course, the question is not well defined so I assumed that was the question and gave an example where it happens.